# What is an absolutely simple module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

The simple modules over a ring R are the (left or right) modules over R that are non-zero and have no non-zero proper submodules.

What is the definition of an **absolutely simple module**?

Seen this in Dixmier´s book about enveloping algebras.

Remark: Someone marked my question as closed and associated it with another question about irreducible modules. I dont see how this is related, so please comment, if you have a problem. Thank you.

Comment: The way that they are related is that "irreducible module" is a synonym for "simple module".  So it seems to be the same question with one word switched.

Comment: @rschwieb I don´t think you are right, see the José´s answer below please.

Comment: His answer confirms what I said. In the context here, [Irreducible module is a synonym for simple module](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Irreducible_module&redirect=no).  An `absolutely simple/irreducible module` is defined in terms of `simple/irreducible modules`.   Maybe you think the last sentence contradicts me, but if you do, then you did not read what I wrote correctly.  He is simply saying that the notion of an absolutely simple module is stronger than a simple/irreducible module.

Comment: @rschwieb Okay, since the answer is deleted and the question closed anyway, nevermind.